# How to set a specific frame in android animation

Tags: android, animation

I have a frame-by-frame animation and I want to set a specific frame when the stop method has been called. I searched a lot but I haven't found what I was serching for.

Does this method exists? Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Use this method on your AnimationDrawable: animationDrawable.selectDrawable(index)

Comment: This does not seem to do anything at all for me. I have 7 frames in my  animation, it starts out at frame 0 and when I do myAnimation.selectDrawable(5) for example it does not change at all.

Comment: AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable)frameImage.getBackground();
        animationDrawable.stop();
        animationDrawable.selectDrawable(0);  This is my code

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that frame-by-frame means **AnimationDrawable** given in the background of an **ImageView**.
Like that (or via xml):

```
        AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = new AnimationDrawable();
        animationDrawable.addFrame(drawableFrame1, 0);
        animationDrawable.addFrame(drawableFrame2, 1);
        animationDrawable.addFrame(drawableFrame3, 2);
        animationDrawable.addFrame(drawableFrame4, 3);
        iv = new ImageView(this);
        iv.setBackgroundDrawable(animationDrawable);
```

Here is the code to retrieve a given frame and set it to the background of the **ImageView**

```
      onStop() {
            Drawable drawableFrame2 = ((AnimationDrawable)iv.getBackground()).getFrame(2);
            iv.setBackgroundDrawable(drawableFrame2);
            iv.postInvalidate();
      }
```

Comment: I would like to re-use the animation. The stop method that I use is the stop method of the AnimationDrawable class, not the onStop()